# How to modify rc.local in shell script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, rc

I want to add a line(such as `'*/data/mod/myservice start some_parameter*'`.) to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file in shell script. If there exists a line start with `'*/data/mod/myservice start*'`, then **replace it** by new one.

In my script, it execute the next python method.

```
def excuteCmd(cmd):
    import commands
    output = commands.getoutput(cmd)

def setTask(cmd, installFlag):
    print cmd, installFlag
    excuteCmd('cat /etc/rc.d/rc.local >  oldTask')
    input = open('oldTask','r')
    emptyFile = False
    lines = input.readlines()
    input.close()
    taskNum = len(lines)
    output = open('newTask', 'w')
    if (taskNum  == 0):
            if (installFlag):
                    output.write(cmd + '\n')
    else:
            for i in range(taskNum):
                    if (lines[i].find(cmd) == -1):
                            output.write(lines[i])
            if (installFlag):
                    output.write(cmd + '\n')
    output.close()
    excuteCmd('sudo cat newTask > /etc/rc.d/rc.local')
    excuteCmd('rm -f oldTask')
    excuteCmd('rm -f newTask')
```

But when i execute `sudo cat newTask > /etc/rc.d/rc.local`, it raise the following error.

`-bash: /etc/rc.d/rc.local: Permission denied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you don't have permission to either write to or delete the file. Also, you won't be able to run the `sudo` command like that without typing in a password, so ideally the script itself would be run using `sudo python scriptname`.

Comment: Also, I think I'm right, the sudo command only refers to the thing that are executed before the > sign, not after. jknupp probably know that, but I did'nt think it was clear in his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`sudo command > filename` executes `command` using `sudo` (with root privileges), but writes into the `filename` with user's privileges (insufficient to write to /etc). Imagine it like this:

```
(sudo command) > filename
```

The `sudo` applies to the bracketed part only.

You could run your whole script using `sudo`.